# RecyclerView Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, model-view-controller, butterknife

I'm new to Android Studio, and have found similar questions but none with replies that apply to my current instance. I've been trying to work with **RecyclerViews** and have been getting the following error message whenever I open an activity with it. The code doesn't show any errors.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lucasrizzotto.edgeweather/com.lucasrizzotto.edgeweather.ui.HourlyForecastActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
```

This is my adapter:

```
public class HourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HourAdapter.HourViewHolder> {

    private Hour[] mHours;

    public HourAdapter(Hour[] hours) {
        mHours = hours;
    }

    @Override
    public HourViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.hourly_list_item, parent, false);
        HourViewHolder viewHolder = new HourViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(HourViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bindHour(mHours[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mHours.length;
    }

    public class HourViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView mTimeLabel;
        public TextView mTemperatureLabel;
        public TextView mSummaryLabel;
        public ImageView mIconImageView;

        public HourViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTimeLabel = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeLabel);
            mTemperatureLabel = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.temperatureLabel);
            mSummaryLabel = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.summaryLabel);
            mIconImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iconImageView);
        }

        public void bindHour(Hour hour) {
            mTimeLabel.setText(hour.getHour());
            mSummaryLabel.setText(hour.getSummary());
            mTemperatureLabel.setText((int)hour.getTemperature());
            mIconImageView.setImageResource(hour.getIconId());
        }

    }
}
```

And my Activity class (Keep in mind I'm using the ButterKnife plugin to avoid boilerplate code)

```
public class HourlyForecastActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Hour[] mHours;

    @BindView(R.id.recyclerView) RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hourly_forecast);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Parcelable[] parcelables = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(MainActivity.HOURLY_FORECAST);
        mHours = Arrays.copyOf(parcelables, parcelables.length, Hour[].class);

        HourAdapter adapter = new HourAdapter(mHours);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    }
}
```

What am I overlooking?

Thanks in advance for the wisdom!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try calling:

```
ButterKnife.bind(this);
```

after setting the content view

Since you are not doing this the conventional way, you need to actually call bind().

Comment: Hi, Kushan, thank you for your reply! I tried your suggestion and got a new error instead: 

FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                               Process: PID: 19348
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x4b

Comment: whats the error? this is actually the correct answer for your previous exception.

Comment: you are missing some String reference that you used somewhere

Comment: Well, you've solved the first problem, so thank you (:

Comment: you're welcome :) @SexualPotatoes, btw loved your username xD

Comment: haha , thanks! Not sure how I even got it. I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding the Adapter, ViewHolder, LayoutManager (etc) pattern, do you have any resources you could recommend me?

Comment: I myself am actually a beginner, been developing in android since a month. I used Android programming: The big ranch nerd guide.... It's an awesome book for beginners given that they know java very well ;)

Comment: gotten more than pretty good now ;) all thanks to this book for making my basics clear.. try it out. Else stack is always there :)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 3):

You are using ButterKnife to bind views which is good.

But it seems that you have **forgotten to initialise ButterKnife** for your current Activity.

Just do this,

```
ButterKnife.bind(this);
```

after this line,

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_hourly_forecast);
```

This **will initialise ButterKnife for your current Activity** and you will be able to reference the RecyclerView from your layout correctly.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Aritra! You got it exactly right.

Comment: I would, but I don't have 15 reputation yet. It won't let me.

Answer (score 1):

Basicly you need to initialized mRecyclerView

For example

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
```

But in your case you use ButterKnife library for this.

So you need to call its bind() method after setContentView(R.layout.activity_hourly_forecast);

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_hourly_forecast);
ButterKnife.bind(this);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Max! I got a new error now as a result of the change: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: PID: 19348 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x4b

Comment: as i said, you are missing some string reference in your strings.xml which you tried to reference somewhere

Comment: @SexualPotatoes  at a which line?